# Is there a faster alternative to for loops? apply family of functions?

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, tidyverse, apply

I have this code - but it is superslow on my fairly powerful laptop. Ive hear that the apply() family of functions is better and faster. This takes about 20 minutes for me. Any help is appreciated!

```
# DOWNLOAD data from scb

# PXWEB query
pxweb_query_list <-
  list("ContentsCode"=c("PR0101D3"),
       "Tid"=c("*"))

# Download data
px_data <-
  pxweb_get(url = "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/PR/PR0101/PR0101A/KPI12MNy",
            query = pxweb_query_list)

# Convert to data.frame
px_data_frame <- as.data.frame(px_data, column.name.type = "text", variable.value.type = "text")

# 1: Recursive pseudo–out–of–sample forecasts

# extract inflation values
cpi <- px_data_frame[, 2]


# Define as time series
cpi <- ts(cpi, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 12)

# Calculate matrix size for the forcast period:
# (2021 - 2000) * 12 + (12 - 1) + 1 - (24 - 1) = 241

arima_re <- ts(matrix(NA,
                      nrow = 241,
                      ncol = 3),
               start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 12)



for (i in 1:241){
  EndDate <- 1999 + (11/12) + (i-1) / 12

  Data <- window(cpi,
                 end = EndDate)
  Result <- auto.arima(Data)
  arima_re[i, ] <- forecast(Result, h = 3)$mean
  
  print(i)

}
```

Comment: Investigate the `map..()` functions in the `purrr` package. Though `for` loops are not inherently slow in modern versions of R, `apply` and now `map` are often better replacements for many looping conditions.

Comment: It's not the loop that is slow, it's fitting a model 241 times. Running in parallel is probably the best way to speed things up.

Comment: I just realized this aswell. What does running in parallel mean?

Comment: ^ That's what I see as a huge benefit of lists and higher order functions. Since each model is fit independently, you can parallelize the fitting with mclapply() or similar. No need to fit them sequentially.

Comment: Can either Gregor or Bill explain how you do this?

Comment: Quick explanation: lapply is a higher-order function that takes a list and a function, then applies the function to each item in the list, and returns a list of the same length. The order in which the function is applied to a particular item doesn't matter; it can start at the beginning, end, middle, and the return value is the same. Therefore if you have a CPU with, say, 4 cores, mclapply (or similar) can apply the function to 4 items at a time instead of 1.